# How to give border radius to make an element look like this image?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make `.main-div` like this image

[image]

```css
.main-div {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: Red;
  border-radius: 30px/20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div"></div>
```

My JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/teowbLbm/).

Comment: So what's wrong? All you need is add image as background or plain `<img>`

Comment: In your code try adding this value `border-radius: 40px/37px;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do a trick using a pseudo element and achieve that shape

```css
body {
  background: lightgray;
}

.main-div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 110px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 30%/50%;
  background: url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWoXa.png) center center no-repeat;
  background-size: 110px 110px;
}

.main-div::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 5px;
  top: -5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 110px;
  background: inherit;
  background-size: inherit;
  border-radius: 50%/30%;
}

.main-div+.main-div {
  background: gray;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div"></div>
<div class="main-div"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

As [Justinas](//stackoverflow.com/users/1346234/justinas) remarked [in their answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/43731461), the border of your example image does not look like it can be recreated with [`border-radius`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/border-radius) alone. This is because the outline is not an ellipse.

It is possible to do this, with good browser support, using SVG as follows.

```css
/* set size of and center SVG */
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="outline">
      <!-- use Bezier curves to define outline -->
      <path d="M 0 100
               C 0 0, 40 0, 100 0
               C 160 0, 200 0, 200 100
               C 200 200, 160 200, 100 200
               C 40 200, 0 200, 0 100
               Z" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>

  <image x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"
     xlink:href="https://placehold.it/200"
     clip-path="url(#outline)" />
</svg>
```

This uses [clipping in SVG](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Clipping_and_masking) with the [`clipPath`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Element/clipPath) element. You can define any path to use for the clipping. I have used four [Bezier curves](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/SVG/Tutorial/Paths#Bezier_Curves) here. You can tweak where the control points are, or change this to use something entirely different if you wish.

An extra bonus of this approach is that it is now easy to apply other (advanced) filters, for example blurring the image or applying a drop shadow.

```css
/* set size of and center SVG */
svg {
  display: block;
  width: 204px;
  height: 204px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="outline">
      <!-- use Bezier curves to define outline -->
      <path d="M 0 100
               C 0 0, 40 0, 100 0
               C 160 0, 200 0, 200 100
               C 200 200, 160 200, 100 200
               C 40 200, 0 200, 0 100
               Z" />
    </clipPath>
    <filter id="dropshadow" x="-30%" y="-30%"
            width="160%" height="160%"
            color-interpolation-filters="sRGB">
      <!-- define color of shadow here -->
      <feComponentTransfer in="SourceAlpha">
        <feFuncR type="linear" slope="0"
                 intercept="0.518"></feFuncR>
        <feFuncG type="linear" slope="0"
                 intercept="0.698"></feFuncG>
        <feFuncB type="linear" slope="0"
                 intercept="0.867"></feFuncB>
      </feComponentTransfer>
      <!-- define blur of shadow here -->
      <feGaussianBlur stdDeviation="2" />
      <!-- we can offset the shadow -->
      <feOffset result="shadow" dx="1" dy="1" />
      <!-- put shadow below original content -->
      <feBlend in="SourceGraphic"
               in2="shadow" mode="normal" />
    </filter>
  </defs>

  <g transform="translate(2, 2)"
     filter="url(#dropshadow)">
    <image x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200"
      xlink:href="https://placehold.it/200"
      clip-path="url(#outline)" />
   </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your image radius does not look like standard CSS border radius. If yes, than you need to use image preprocessing (in back-end side, e.g. GD or stand-alone tool like Photoshop) or use [Clipping Mask](https://css-tricks.com/clipping-masking-css/) with limited support. Using border radius you can have similar effect.

```css
.main-div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 40%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

.main-div img {
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  left: -50px;
  top: -50px;
  margin-top: 50%;
  margin-left: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main-div">
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/"/>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this style. You can change `border-radius` as per your requirements:

```css
div {
  border: 2px solid #a1a1a1;
  padding: 10px 15px; `enter code here`
  background: #dddddd;
  width: 100px;
  border-radius: 55px;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```css
.element {
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://imgbb.com/"><img src="https://image.ibb.co/irvmO5/html5.png" alt="html5" border="0" class="element"></a><br /><a target='_blank' href='https://imgbb.com/'>Rounded rectangle clip mask</a>
```

Comment: .element {
  border-radius: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
}



outside of border radius image is hidden.



first, make the 50px border and after that hide outside corner.through clip mask